# If $\lim_{x \to b^{-}} f(x) = d$ then the image of $f$ is the half closed interval $[f(a),d)$ - Proof feedback

Tags: calculus, proof-writing, solution-verification, monotone-functions

Let $f:[a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a strictly monotone increasing continuous function on a half closed interval $[a,b)$, and let $d$ be a real number.

Prove that if $\lim_{x \to b^{-}}f(x) = d$ then the image of $f$ is the half closed interval $[f(a),d)$

So I tried to work out this proof and wanted feedback if I used the right approach.

**Attempt:**

Observe since $f$ is monotonically increasing we know that since $a < b \Rightarrow f(a) < f(b) \leq d$. This then means that $d - f(a) > 0$

Also for $f$ to be the image of $[f(a),b)$ means that $f(a) \leq f(x) < d$. At least my interpretation of what it means.

As such, we are given that $\lim_{b \to b^{-}} = d$ which by definition means that for $\epsilon > 0$ and for all $c \in [a,b)$, there exists a $\delta$ such that if $|x - c|< \delta$ then $|f(x) - d| < \epsilon$. If we choose $\epsilon = d - f(a)$ then we have: (this is the step I'm weary of)

$$|f(x) - d| < \epsilon \\ d-\epsilon < f(x) < d < d+\epsilon \\ d - (d-f(a)) < f(x) < d < d + (d-f(a)) \\ f(a) < f(x) < d$$

Therefore the image of $f$ is $[f(a),d)$

I'm not sure if I am able to choose $\epsilon$. But another side of me feels that is what needs to be done because I'm trying to show a specific image set not an arbitrary one.

Feedback on the attempt?

Comment: Just edited it.

Comment: Monotonically increasing means $f(x) \leq f(y)$ for $x <y$. So your function can be  a constant. I think you really meant strictly increasing instead of monotonically increasing.

Comment: Correct @KaviRamaMurthy, going to edit

Answer (score 2):

You have two sets, image of $f$ and $[f(a),d)$ and you want to show their equality. The former is a subset of latter by monotonicity and the latter is a subset of former by intermediate value theorem. You're done!

Comment: Could you be a bit more explicit in what you mean? I have an idea of what you're getting at with the use of IVT, but don't completely see how it is applied.

Comment: @dc3rd: Consider any arbitrary $y \in [f(a), d)$. You want to show that there exists $x \in [a, b)$ such that $f(x) = y$. Since $\lim_{x \to b^-}f(x) = d$ and $y <d$, we see that there exists $x_0 \in [a, b)$ such that $f(a) \le y < f(x_0) < b$. Thus, by IVT, there exists $x \in [a, x_0)$ such that $f(x) = y$.