# If $\lim_{x \to b^{-}}f(x) = \infty$ then the image of $f$ is the ray $[f(a),\infty)$ - Proof feedback

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, monotone-functions

Let $f:[a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a strictly monotone increasing continuous function on a half closed interval $[a,b)$, and let $d$ be a real number.

**Claim:** If $\lim_{x \to b^{-}}f(x) = \infty$ then the image of $f$ is the ray $[f(a),\infty)$

This question is a follow up to another one I did that most likely applies:
[If $\lim_{x \to b^{-}} f(x) = d$ then the image of $f$ is the half closed interval $[f(a),d)$ - Proof feedback](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3749232/if-lim-x-to-b-fx-d-then-the-image-of-f-is-the-half-closed-interv)

So in that question we established that the image of $f$ is the half closed interval $[f(a),d)$.

For this question, I wanted to apply this result and let $d = \infty$. Then the result will follow. I think this is correct, but something is telling me that I can't treat $\infty$'s in such a cavalier way. So do I need to be more confident in my solutions or am I right in wanting to tread more carefully due to  the $\infty$ ?

Comment: Your proof won't go through exactly due to the $\epsilon$ nature of it but the result is indeed true. Do you see any way to adapt the previous way to show it?

Comment: What do you mean by the $\epsilon$ nature? Do you mean from the last proof when I let $\epsilon = d - f(a)$?

Comment: For each $\delta > 0$, $f(x) > M$ whenever $a < |x - x_0| < b$

Comment: @dc3rd: correct. When talking about $\infty$, it does not make sense to talk about "an $\epsilon$ neighbourhood of $\infty$" and so, the proof would need modification.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani well by definition the limit diverging means: For all $M > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that if $0< |x - b| < \delta$ then $f(x) > M$.

Comment: @dc3rd: as opposed to diverging (which (usually) just means "not converging"), I would say "diverges to $\infty$" but yes, that is correct. Do you see how you can conclude now?

Comment: @AryamanMaithani if I were to "let" $M = f(a)$ then this would stand for all $x \in [a,b)$ because $f$ is monotonic. Thus $M = f(a) < f(x)$

Comment: @dc3rd: It would stand for all $x \in {\color{red}(}a, b)$ since you need strict inequality, yes but I don't see that being very helpful.

Comment: Still don't see how to draw my conclusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Claim 1.** $\operatorname{im}f \subset [f(a), \infty)$.
*Proof.* Follows from monotonicity.

---

**Claim 2.** $\operatorname{im}f \supset [f(a), \infty)$.

*Proof.* Let $y_0 \in [f(a), \infty)$. We need to show that there exists $x_0 \in [a, b)$ such that $f(x_0) = y_0$.

Let $M = y_0$ (as in the notation in the comments).
Let $\delta$ be as in the comments. Choose any $x \in [a, b)$ that satisfies $0 < |x - b| < \delta$. Then, we have $f(x) > M$.

On the other hand, we have $f(a) \le y_0 < f(x)$.
By IVT, we see that there exists $x_0 \in [a, x)$ such that $f(x_0) = y_0$, as desired.

---

Equality of $\operatorname{im} f$ and $[f(a), \infty)$ now follow.

Comment: I made the same mistake I made in the last question in not considering to show equality of the two sets. I also really need to flesh out the meanings of what it is I need to exactly prove so I have a more concrete objective. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @dc3rd: that reminds me of [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gxqq3.jpg)! :D

Comment: @AryamanMaithani: good observation. My own rule of thumb: easier questions in introductory analysis are just about definitions and nature of order relations, the difficult ones involve completeness of real numbers.